# Is it feasible to encrypt a file in 1mb chunks?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, block, filestream

I was encrypting files in chunks on 16 bits but I noticed how long it is taking so I tried 1mb chunks but the only thing that's bothering me is that if for example the file is 600.5 mb after encryption/decryption it becomes 601mb. is this harmful to the file data? does it corrupt the file or something? here's the loop that does the chunk by chunk encryption:

```
ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, symmetricKey.IV);
CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                for (long i = 0; i < fsInput.Length; i += chunkSize)
                {
                    if (sender == "main")
                    {
                        MainWindow.valuee += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PasswordEnter.valuee += 1;
                    }
                    byte[] chunkData = new byte[chunkSize];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = fsInput.Read(chunkData, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
                    {
                        if (bytesRead != chunkSize)
                        {
                            for (int x = bytesRead - 1; x < chunkSize; x++)
                            {
                                chunkData[x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        cryptoStream.Write(chunkData, 0, chunkSize);
                    }
                }
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
```

Comment: Did you try to decrypt the file? Did it have the same content as before?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé yeah I tried with a video, it played fine but the filesize was 1 mb more than it used to be

Comment: The decrypted file was bigger than it was before you encrypted it?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé yeah by one mb but it still played perfectly fine EDIT: I just noticed that it increased the size by a few hundred KB's to make it a perfect 421 mb instead of 420.2mb

Comment: Ok, for a video file that might work. But I would not recommend to try it with other file types, this might destroy them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last loop, you use `chunkSize` in the `cryptoStream.Write`.

Try with the `bytesRead`.

```
cryptoStream.Write(chunkData, 0, bytesRead);
```